# Add OnTap to a TitleBar

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I need to be able to hide the grid(what's under the Food titlebar)  when the food title bar is tapped.

From what I have found  I had to use Event Delegation, but for some reason my testing with an Alert() didnt do anything when I had click on Food TitleBar.

Can someone help me?  (Using architect, so it would be easier for me to have the solution using architect since most of the code generated is ReadOnly -_-')

[image: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/5809/capturedecran20130523a1.png]

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Quite simply

I added a delegate event binding.
I opened it (architect) and wrote down in it : alert('test');
nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used architect once. But Im pretty sure there is an interface to edit the code that it is generated. [Here is the demo to implement a click on the titlebar](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/kuSAC/2/).

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.home', {
            extend: 'Ext.Container',
            xtype: 'homecontainer',
            config: {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    title: 'test',
                    dock: 'top',
                    listeners: {
                        painted: function (element, opt) {
                            element.on('tap', function () {
                                alert('Test');
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.home'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I have seen something similar to that elsewhere, but it didnt explain what was going on with painted? isn't it like in Java where painted is for the ''rendering'?

i wil try to do such a thing in architect.

Comment: Painted is an event that fires after the component is rendered on the screen. We attach a tap event listener once the component is rendered. Should be similar to java painting(Not really sure).